# 5 and 95th whiskers with sglot?

Tags: sas

Is it possible to choose the whisker value with proc sgplot.
Because it seems only 25th and 75th are avalaible for SGPLOT.

Maybe someone know if it is possible or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to add non-standard whiskers, probably because it is discouraged by statisticians.

They discourage it because the boxplot has a specific definition in terms of the quartiles.
While there are occasional variations, (i.e., to get a rough normality plot), 
in general people expect to see quartiles in a box plot.
Adding arbitrary percentiles, even ones that make sense like the ones you propose,
is likely to confuse the audience more than it helps.

Try this visualization: A waterfall graph of sales contributions based on the percentile intervals you suggest:

```
data actualBinned; set sashelp.prdsale;
   keep actual;
run;
proc rank data=actualBinned out=actualBinned
     groups=100
     descending;
   var actual;
   ranks rank;
run;
data actualBinned; set actualBinned;
   if      rank < 5  then bin="00-05";
   else if rank < 25 then bin="05-25";
   else if rank < 50 then bin="25-50";
   else if rank < 75 then bin="50-75";
   else if rank < 95 then bin="75-95";
   else                   bin="95-100";
run;
proc sort data=actualBinned;
   by bin;
run;
proc sgplot data=actualBinned;
  waterfall category=bin response=actual;
run;
```

I am not a huge fan of bins of different width displayed with the same width. I would rather use 20 bins of width 5.
With that caveat, I can see how a manager might find this visualization more useful in a specific context.

BTW, the waterfall graph is experimental in 9.3. For older version of SAS there are several recipes online.